# App is not listed in Google Play Search

Tags: android, google-play

I know it is a redundant question but I tried to solve the problem but with no success.

I published an App in Google Play Store a week ago. But I'm still not able to find it in the search. I tried to search by App name, package name and by the developer name and it is not there. When I click on the developer name I get only my other App. The App name is not in English and there are few apps have similar keywords. I have contact Google but I didn't get any result till now. Any suggestion about how to track such an issue? Should I change package name or delete the App and republish it?

I can only access to my App using the URL that is provided in the Google Play Console.

Here is the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="-----------">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />


        <application
            android:name=".PUSH_UP_NOTIFICATION"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/doc_luncher_icon2"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/doc_luncher_icon2_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity android:name=".State_Activity" />
            <activity android:name=".GetDoctorInfoActivity" />

            <meta-data
                android:name="com.parse.SERVER_URL"
                android:value="@string/back4app_server_url" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.parse.APPLICATION_ID"
                android:value="@string/back4app_app_id" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.parse.CLIENT_KEY"
                android:value="@string/back4app_client_key" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.parse.push.gcm_sender_id"
                android:value="id:-------" />

            <activity android:name=".ViewDoctors" />
            <activity android:name=".SignUpActivity" />
            <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
            <activity android:name=".DoctorManagingActivity" />
            <activity android:name=".GetAppointmentActivity" />
            <activity android:name=".ShowPatientQueue" />
            <activity android:name=".SearchForDoctorActivity" />
            <activity android:name=".AboutActivity" />
            <activity android:name=".ContactUsActivity" />
            <activity android:name=".PatientAppointmentsActivity" />

            <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

            <receiver
                android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
                android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                    <category android:name="---------------" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
            <receiver
                android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
                android:exported="false">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                    <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
                    <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
            <activity android:name=".ResetPasswordActivity" />
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

I'm using Parse and Firebase for push notification, so most of the Permissions are for them.

Comment: Search with your package name once

Comment: Have you checked what countries you've made it available in?

Comment: I can't find it by package name!!

Comment: It is listed for 141+ countries

Comment: please share the link of your application

Comment: try to search through the web browser on play.google.com

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko, I tried and it is not there. However, I can find it in https://www.appbrain.com/apptimizer

Comment: then it is not programming-related problem

Comment: I'm new in Android programming, and not sure if my manifest is fully correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who may face the same issue and avoid asking to not get negative rating! 
Here is how I have solved mine:

I have contacted Google support several times, and I have received several premade emails about new Apps with low ranking and needing time . However, I insisted that it is not the case, so the support team has escalated the problem to their engineers ("as they said"). After couple of days I get this email from them:

> Hi again,
>
> Thanks for your patience while our team investigated this issue.
>
> I received word today to ask you to do the following for your app:
>
> Select the app in the Play Console Navigate to Store Presence >
>   Pricing & Distribution Click "Manage countries" Scroll to the bottom
>   and un-check "Rest of the world" Re-check "Rest of the world" Click
>   Submit Update
>
> Once you've done this for all four apps, they should start to show up
>   in search results again within a few hours.

And after following the instruction, now I can find my app as first in the search result.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't find it with this link (add your application id at the end of it)

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=[APPLICATION_ID]
```

Than you have not published your app correctly.

Go to the play store console -> all apps and check if "published" is mentioned on the right side of your app entry.
Also go to the release dashboard and check what is mentioned there.

Finally check if you missed something by going through that checklist here: https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/launch/launch-checklist

It is possible that you simply forgot to configure some stuff like age restrictions etc

Comment: In the Console it says "Published". And when I use the URL you provide and use Package Name instead of [APPLICATION_ID], I can see my App. I went through all store listing options several times and I couldn't find anything wrong or missing

Comment: Can you see it when you use an incognito tab?

Comment: I found in old question that you may need to add 'support-screens' not sure if this is still applicable

Comment: I just tried it  incognito tab, if use the direct URL, yes I can. And tried searching by name and it is not there

Comment: Can you share a link to your application?

Comment: and how is that going to make a difference?

Comment: We can than try to search for ourselves. If we find it there must be something wrong on your side

Comment: I just tried to use a proxy website. When I searched in Google Store, My App was the first App in the result. However, if I use regular browser or Store App on several phones, never get shows in the result

Comment: So the app is not available in your region? Some filter is blocking YOU to see it

Comment: I sent an another email to Google and still waiting for them to respond

Comment: Must be the most ugliest app ever if you do not share the name or package... I am out of here, better things to do than wasting time with someone who dodges questions

Comment: Thank you for concern, the reason I didn't share the app link because it is not in English. Thank you again for your time